# How to implement security model in MS CRM?

Tags: c#, .net, security, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to secure certain information in MS-CRM. What is the best approach to restrict a user from reading everybody's e-mails or reading certain contacts?

Is this done on the UI or by .NET code. I've researched the security model [MS-CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309524.aspx) but cant find a decent example or small walk-through to get started.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I've been interacting very litlle with MSCRM, mainly thru code, using SDK. It may be my unexperience with the UI and the system in general.

We need to secure thousands of emails from users accounts and a few contacts. There seems to be many ways to implement the security, such as for example the 2 links below.

http://dynamics2011.blogspot.com/2012/04/crm-2011-utilizing-role-based-security.html
  -CRM 2011 using roles, teams, and business units seems "easier" than below
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/07/27/making-crm-records-private/
  -CRM 2011 using roles, teams, and business units (this has 2 options)

Any idea on which would be a better?, or maybe someone has another idea. I'm looking for something simple.

Comment: There are many ways to implement and structure a security model and generally is very much depends on what you are trying to achieve. I think we need to know more about the requirement (e.g. who can see what, who shouldnt be able to what) before we can really make a decent contribution that is specific to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect hagensoft, (and don't take this as harshly as it may sound) I'm not sure how you can be confused over whether security is implemented via UI or .Net code if you've researched the chapter you link to (It's via UI). I say this, as I'm not sure what can be told to you, that isn't already behind that link (or linked directly from it).

Users have roles. The sum of roles determines a user's permissions and access rights. Roles can restrict access to records either wholesale or depending on the ownership of the record to be secured (therefore depending on the highest privilege you have for that record type, a record owned by you, a co-worker in the same business unit, a parent business unit or anywhere in the organisation may be accessible to you).

Perhaps you can describe what you've tried to do and what is specifically causing problems...